# Are ERC777 & ERC223 smart contracts superior to ERC20 smart contracts?

Tags: tokens

I have been reading some articles which claim that ERC223 and ERC777 have all the features of ERC20 plus additional features which makes them a superior contract. If this is the case, why are they not more widely implemented than ERC20 smart contracts? Are there security tradeoffs to using ERC777 and ERC223 over ERC20?

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it like the ERC20 is the base class. So when saying an ERC20 token it could be any extension of ERC20, whether ERC223, ERC777 or others. 
So indeed wallets and apps who supports ERC20 tokens, do support also ERC223 and ERC777. 
It’s a matter of choice if you want to add extra features and security features to your token.

Comment: In this regard, would ERC721 be considered another base class given its non-fungible characteristics?

Comment: Exactly, ERC721 is the base class for non-fungible tokens